# Woocommerce Which template holds custom checkout fields?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I added some custom-fields to the `woocommerce` checkout form. When I get the `order-details`-page in I can see that those custom fields are wrapped in a table with the class `woocommerce-table woocommerce-table--custom-fields shop_table custom-fields`. Where can I find the file which contains these fields? I need to know for styling purpose.

**EDIT**
I use the `Woo Checkout Form Editor`-plugin to create the custom checkout fields.

Comment: See my updated question...

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Woocommerce --> Include--class-wc-customer.php
If you want to add a custom field by code you can try this code as well.
Paste this code in the active child theme.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_field');

function custom_checkout_field($checkout)

{

echo '<div id="custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('New Heading') . '</h2>';

woocommerce_form_field('custom_field_name', array(

'type' => 'text',

'class' => array(

'my-field-class form-row-wide'

) ,

'label' => __('Custom Additional Field') ,

'placeholder' => __('New Custom Field') ,

) ,

$checkout->get_value('custom_field_name'));

echo '</div>';

}
```